# Editing an alarm !

Tags: android, alarm

I am setting an alarm for my reminder app:

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddToDoList.this, 
          Integer.parseInt(DBHelperClass.getMaxPrimaryId()), intent, 0);
```

i am using a unique value (primary ID) to set an alarm. When i want to edit the alarm i am using the same key. But what i see is that both the alarms go off! original as well as edited one.

how do i cancel the old alarm ?
Also these alarms are not working once i switchOff & then again switchOn my device .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do i cancel the old alarm ?

Call `cancel()` with your original `PendingIntent`.

> Also these alarms are not working once
>   i switchOff & then again switchOn my
>   device .

Alarms do not persist after a reboot. You will need to reschedule the alarms, possibly by a [`BroadcastReceiver` that gets control at boot time](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm/).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing the way you make Intents unique - `requestCode` is not officially defined. Try keeping Intent's data different for example.

About persisting the alarm trough reboots, I'm not sure but maybe [RTC_WAKEUP flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP) is the closest you can get.